# Can't get rid of a border on an ion-img image

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, border

I have images in my code, but they appear with borders what I can't remove for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
<ion-img class="whatsapp-welcome"></ion-img>

.whatsapp-welcome {
  margin-top: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-image: url("../../assets/whatsapp.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: bottom left;
  }
```

and the image is being rendered looks like this:

[image]

I have tried `border: none` and `text-decoration: none` but nothing works!

Is there any way to remove the image border?

Update:
I just checked the image doesnt have borders.

[image]

This is what I get when I put

[image]

Comment: Maybe your image have border! Try other images

Comment: There might be some higher level css in your codebase that are giving your images this border.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your css class. whatsapp-welcome. Three possible issues, One the image itself has the image. Second, there is a parent css class that is adding the border (due to css specificity). Third, there might be some wired focus issue adding that border.

Comment: To help me understand: Why are you putting a background image in an `<img>` tag (whether using ionic or not)?  What does it look like if you use `<ion-img [src]="../../assets/whatsapp.png" class="your-img"></ion-img>` without the background css?

Comment: @RobMoll it doesnt work just show an image with errors.

Comment: ionic's `<ion-img>` have some issues. try html's `<img src="../imagename.png">` tag and check if border appears or not.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib it worked! thx!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was ion-img.
After I changed to img-src it worked fine!